# Special characters in JSON string - results in "<null>"

Tags: json, swift, character-encoding

I'm having trouble using the results of an API call when the resulting content contains accented characters (like `ñ` or `é`).

The following is the code I use:

```
let url = "http://example.com/fetchdata.php"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
request.addValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let params = ["country":selectedCountry] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    if let d = data {
        let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d, options: .AllowFragments) as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
        // do some work on the resulting json object
        // This is where the trouble starts!
    }
})
```

If the results contain only plain, non-accented characters, everything works fine, otherwise casting the `json` object into `[Dictionary<String, String>]` fails. If I run

```
print(try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d, options: .AllowFragments))
```

It shows that the offending fields in the array as `"<null>"`.

I'm not even converting the data I get from the server into `String` at any point, so I'm not sure where I can force it to use UTF8 encoding, if it's not doing it now. How can I fix it?

---

**Edit**
Indeed, this turned out to be a server issue. Specifying the charset in the php script did the trick:

```
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Curiously, this was not necessary when the data was going in and out of the db using a set of identically configured custom php scripts, but that broke once the data was added using the Import functionality of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: It's probably an encoding issue *on the server*.

Comment: Did you encode fetchdata.php with the UTF-8 encoding ?